# Lower space between text and border

Tags: html, css

My `HTML`

```
        <div id="ctl00_cphBreadCrumb_TDDF5635D005_ctl00_ctl00_Breadcrumb" class="RadSiteMap RadSiteMap_Sitefinity">
             <li class="rsmItem sfBreadcrumbNavigation">
              <a class="rsmLink" href="default">Default</a>
                 <span class="arrow"> &gt;</span>
               </li> 
               <li class="rsmItem sfNoBreadcrumbNavigation">
                   <span style="color: #999;font-family: myriadpro-bold-webfont;font-size: 10px;">Services</span>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.rsmLink {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #044470 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #044470 !important;
    font-family: myriadpro-bold-webfont !important;
    font-size: 10px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

But I am getting some space between link and border. If I use underline instead of border it is not that much below as expected. I want space between what border is giving and what underline is giving. And border should be little less in size than it is. Could you please help me?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82tUA/)
Thanks.

Comment: here's a fiddle of your code http://jsfiddle.net/82tUA/

Comment: sorry, i did not get where you changed?

Comment: I didn't change anything.. I've just made a fiddle with your code :)

Comment: so you want no space between text and border ?

Comment: there should be space but somewhat less than default one.

Comment: ok i think its about the descendants of the typeface see this: https://www.fontshop.com/glossary/
i will try something

Answer (score 0):

It's much of a muchness between `text-decoration` and `border-bottom`, but you could try using a pseudo element like this:

```
.rsmLink:before
{
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #044470;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/82tUA/2/)**

If that's not exactly what you need, you could play with the bottom rule ... say `bottom:-1px` .

The results looks similar to border-bottom but hey, i'll let you do the squinting.

Comment: increase height to 3px and observe unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Why would you increase the height? Do you need a border thickness  > 1px? -.... and if you *do* - again - just adjust the `bottom` rule

Comment: what if what my border 1px above?

Comment: to move the line upwards use a higher value for `bottom` eg `bottom:1px` etc

Answer (score 0):

Just Added `line-height: 11px;` and its done. Thanks for your time dears.

Comment: be careful with the letters like 'yg' , 'j' etc.. try them before